# http.request not receiving data after 300 seconds of long running POST call

Tags: node.js, rest, http, timeout

I have a Node.js application that exposes a rest API. When called, Node.js retrieves data from DB then does a POST call to another server (server B). The server runs for approximately 10 minutes before returning the results.

When I do the call using postman to server B, I get the response as expected. When I do the call using Node.js as described in the previous paragraph, the Node.js code works as expected when calculation time on server B < 300 seconds. When calculation time > 300 seconds, server B returns the answer, but Node.js keeps waiting forever and does not receive it.

Any idea what the issue is?

```
var options = {
uri: 'http://URL/test?n=305',
method: 'POST',
timeout: 1200000,
json: jsonObject,
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("Response Received");

    if(error != null){
        console.log(error);
        res.send(error).status(response.statusCode)
    } else{
        var ServerBResponse = response.body;
        console.log(ServerBResponse);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code for request to server B?

Comment: Hello @MykolaBorysyuk. I updated the question with a sample of the code I am using.